# VirtualBox: recovering aborted VM

Tags: virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox 4.3.0 on OS X 10.9, and I somehow got my Ubuntu Server 13.10 VM into an aborted state. Now I can't do anything about it; `startvm`, `controlvm poweroff`, or whatever all fail to work. To make things worse, I don't have any snapshots. In this case, is it possible to recover the vm? I've googled for a solution but surprisingly I didn't find anything.

If you are certain that no solution exists, please also leave a comment/answer. Thanks.

---

Update:

Feeling doubtful about the chances of recovery, I deleted the VM and started from scratch. This VM was rather new (built after 13.10 release), so hopefully configuring a new one to normal working state won't consume too much time.

Therefore, I won't be able to test any suggested solutions. Anyway, comments and answers are still welcome, as they may benefit future users with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) running in a separate VM to mount the "ailing" VM's VDI drive where you can then do all the normal system recover tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue where one of my VMs was in an 'Aborted' status, and the first time I tried to restart it, it actually locked-up the host system.  I was able to recover using [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/) (TRK).  The steps I took were:

- In the system settings I removed the Hard Drive from the boot list (Settings->System) to prevent it from locking-up in in case I accidentally tried to boot from the HDD again
- I did a reset on the VM, and hit F12 to select the boot device (a different BIOS may require a different method for that)
- I selected Devices->Optical Drives->Choose/Create disk image, and pointed it to the ISO for TRK
- Back on the boot device menu, I selected Optical Drive.  My VM booted TRK, which then allowed me to repair the VDI problems

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps...

I happened to me yesterday because I tentatively upgraded VirtualBox to the latest version (with the extension pack), found out that the new version was broken.

Thus, I downgraded to the previous version, however the previous extension pack was not asked. I tried and restarted some VMs, some worked but others were in the Aborted VM status.

I reinstalled to extension pack and everything was back to normal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1137116)

Comment: Sorry to disagree but this is one of the solutions regarding the 'Aborted VM' issue.
VirtualBox doesn't provide more information when it throws such error message.
I thought it was worth a short comment.